# POST request to Laravel then download string as a file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have an ajax POST request being sent to a laravel controller, this works fine. I do some work in the controller and I get a string that can vary in size from a few hundred kilobytes to hundreds of megabytes.

I want to download this string as a file and I've been trying various methods, but the problem is whenever I use return to pass the string to a different controller or a different page it returns the output to the ajax success instead. I've tried removing the success, but it still does not work.

```
            /*POST request*/
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"{{ URL::route('sshDownload') }}",
                data: {
                    id:id
                    file:file,
                    status:"logfile"
                },
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("SUCCESS");
                }
            });
```

In my `sshDownload` controller I'm trying to do something like this:

```
        return Response::make($output, '200', array(
            'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="file.log'
        ));
```

and I've even tried:

```
        return Redirect::route('sshDownloadName')->with($output);
```

but in the end, anytime I use return it sends the data back to to the front end ajax.

How can I download the string directly from PHP instead of sending it to ajax?

Comment: What's your base controller type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from your question what you're after -- but this sounds like a Javascript problem, and not a Laravel problem.

When you tell javascript to make an AJAX request, you're telling the browser

> Hey, download this URL in the background and let me know when you're done.

An AJAX response will **never** trigger a browser page refresh or a file download.  Instead of an AJAX request, you need to redirect the entire browser (either via `document.location`, `window.open` or something similar) to another page entirely.

Comment: Yeah I figured it wasn't a laravel issue. I've been trying to stop the success in Ajax, but this doesn't work. So would I have to submit a form or something ?

Comment: @Envious Ignore the previous comment, I missed you needed POST.  Yes, standard Javascript technique is creating a form and then posting it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit